# Auto Fill Webform through Word doc in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

hey i'm working on project in which I have `webform` which includes some `editfields`. I don't want to enter the data manually into that editfield. what I want is to extract data from a word document and fill that `editfields`. But the catch is, through which **MS doc** I fill the **editfield**?

Suppose We have a bunch of lectures uploaded on some page. so what should I do to retrieve the data from a particular document?

1. Is it necessary to open the MS-doc file first?
2. or I should download the file first?

If I goes with option **1** when should I have to use some library? what opens the file within browser, retrieve the data and the a pop-up message appears "the data has been retrieved now you can close the file". and next I can fill the form with that data.

or should I goes with the **2** Option when an individual hit the download button then the file will be stored into the local machine. how can I keep the **track** that which **ms-file** is downloaded or stored into the local machine?and is it necessary to open that file for retrieving the data again?

These are my **point of views** that how I can implement that module. So I need your suggestions? Is this the right way to **achieve** this **goal** or should I follow the other path? and which libraries are required to achieve this task or any tutorial similar to this problem ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: By "editfield" I'm assuming you mean a `TextBox`?

Comment: Yeah u r right sorry actually i was working on an android so i mixed it up.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest considering a third option: since the Word document files exist on the server, the cleanest place to pre-populate a form would be by extracting data from the document while it is on the server and filling in the form's fields before sending it down to the user in a codebehind.  Trying to extract data on the client side from a recently-downloaded file via an application other than the browser seems ripe for kludgy-ness.  Articles such as http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 should help get you started in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for your response. I will let you know soon :)

Answer (score 0):

For extracting data from ms word document using free [.net word component](https://freeword.codeplex.com/) and fill data to webform,

extract data,

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.LoadFromFile("YouDocOrDocx.Docx");
string content = doc.GetText();
```

Comment: @LakshithaRanasingha which question you are talking about ? I already have explained the question.